# Error while updating from 20.04 to 21.04

Tags: apt, updates, 19.10, 21.04

I get the following during the setting up stage. Wifi is working fine.

```
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: There's no update path from 20.04 to 21.04 (it would have to go to 20.10 which is EoL) and error message points to repository that shouldn't be there anyway ("eoan" mean Ubuntu 19.10).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) and [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is correct and expected behavior. You are attempting to release-upgrade to a release that is already past End Of Life (July 2021); those repositories were withdrawn.

There is no constant, tested migration/upgrade path from an LTS release to a non-LTS release. When the calendar is unfortunate (like now) the tested and supported method is to backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu.

FYI: The next 6-month release, Ubuntu 21.10, is scheduled for release in a mere two days. The release you are attempting to install, 21.04, will reach End of Life in a mere three months.

Advice:

1. Backup your data.
2. Create an Ubuntu 21.10 LiveUSB installer.
3. Install 21.10 over 20.04 **without** formatting. The new version of Ubuntu will overwrite the older while leaving your data and customizations unaffected.
4. The backup is in case you make the wrong selection and format instead.

- **Note**: Some folks who migrate from LTS to non-LTS releases are doing so temporarily for *testing*; seeing if hardware or software work with the newer release. You DON'T need to commit to the newer release -- you can use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to conduct accurate, reliable testing while leaving your LTS system untouched.

Comment: Thanks very much will try that

Comment: I do not know but I recently (17Sep2021) updated my ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 21.04 in a single step (without first going to 20.1 and then to 21.04). I did not any such error of repositories not existing.